# Find all the values in a column for a condition in other column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL view named `female` looks like the following

```
+----------+----------+--------+------+
| actor_id | movie_id | gender | year |
+----------+----------+--------+------+
|   528787 |   2      | M      | 1996 |
|   528788 |   2      | F      | 1952 |
|   528789 |   1      | M      | 2001 |
|   528790 |   3      | M      | 1994 |
|   528791 |   2      | F      | 2000 |
|   528791 |   3      | F      | 2004 |
|   528791 |   4      | F      | 2000 |
|   528791 |   5      | F      | 2001 |
|   528792 |   4      | F      | 1999 |
|   528792 |   6      | F      | 2000 |
+----------+----------+--------+------+
```

...and so on

Here the `actor_id` and the `movie_id` form unique combinations. I need to find all the `movie_id` for which ONLY female actors worked. This means I need to exclude all the movies where ONLY male or both male and female actors worked.

**Expected output**

```
+----------+----------+--------+------+
| actor_id | movie_id | gender | year |
+----------+----------+--------+------+
|   528791 |   4      | F      | 2000 |
|   528791 |   5      | F      | 2001 |
|   528792 |   4      | F      | 1999 |
|   528792 |   6      | F      | 2000 |
+----------+----------+--------+------+
```

Please help me understand the solution and what can be the probable query for this.

Sorry if this seems too obvious for some of you people.

The given answers are not correct because I have written a python code to cross verify the values and there I have got count of `18927`.

Comment: Note that in MySQL, views have only very limited access to indexes, rendering them almost entirely pointless (in my 'view')

Answer (score 1):

`NOT EXISTS` comes to mind:

```
select f.*
from female f
where not exists (select 1
                  from female f2
                  where f2.movie_id = f.movie_id and f2.gender = 'M'
                 );
```

If you want only the *movies* but not the original rows, then I would use aggregation:

```
select movie_id
from female f
group by movie_id
having min(gender) = max(gender) and min(gender) = 'F';
```

Comment: The second solution is not working because it shows `253301` unique movies but I have written my python code and the movie counts are `18927`. Just to cross verify.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar . . . The second solution is returning the movies that have only females.  The only consideration I can think of would involve `NULL` values, but your sample data suggests that none are in the data.  I suspect that your Python code is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like following

```
SELECT * 
FROM   [female] 
WHERE  movie_id IN (SELECT movie_id 
                    FROM   [female] 
                    GROUP  BY movie_id 
                    HAVING Max(gender) = Min(gender) 
                           AND Max(gender) = 'F')
```

In case of duplicates in the view and if you don't want the duplicate to appear in your output, you can try like following.

```
 SELECT distinct actor_id , movie_id , gender , year  
    FROM   [female] 
    WHERE  movie_id IN (SELECT movie_id 
                        FROM   [female] 
                        GROUP  BY movie_id 
                        HAVING Max(gender) = Min(gender) 
                               AND Max(gender) = 'F')
```

Comment: The count for you on all the data is `34983` and as I have mentioned that the count should be `18927`. I guess there is some thing wrong going on.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar The above code will not yield unique movie ids, there can be duplicates. Plus your python code could also be incorrect.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar, i have updated the answer and included code to remove duplicates.

Comment: @PSK Is there any way to solve it without `partitionby`??

Comment: Try using DISTINCT or GROUP BY

Comment: can you check now

Comment: The count is still `34982`

Comment: I feel like there is some issue with your python script

Comment: Here is the python script https://pastebin.com/bW22j4J5 and here is the dataset   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VkbxhqhXtqxlNXUEhlc0Rzl8Rhudjm84/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know python :(

Answer (score 1):

Use Not IN On gender 'M':

```
SELECT * FROM `test_data` 
where movie_id 
NOT IN (SELECT movie_id from test_data where gender = 'M')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM female
WHERE gender='F'
AND movieId NOT IN (SELECT movieId FROM female WHERE gender='M');
```